# Unable to deploy laravel application on OpenShift

Tags: ssh, git, openshift-online-2

I have `git push`ed my entire Laravel code base for the application that I had created on my `localhost` to my OpenShift server. But nothing seems to have come out of it. The webpage is still blank. Can someone tell me what changes to make to the application settings so that it gets deployed properly?

I have deployed it at [befikrin-befikrin.rhcloud.com](http://befikrin-befikrin.rhcloud.com).

Can someone please check and let me know what I might be doing wrong here?

While I was running the project on my `localhost` I has deployed it using:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

Do I need to do something on similar lines here?

I tried fetching the logs with `rhc tail` but got the following message:

```
You can tail this application directly with:
ssh -t <MY_SSH_URL> 'tail */log*/*'
Could not parse PKey: no start line
Usage: rhc tail <application>
Pass '--help' to see the full list of options
```

Then I tried it with the `ssh -t...` command suggested above, and this time I got this:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any help at this moment would go a great way as I have been trying to deploy it since yesterday with no avail.

Comment: Exactly how are you deploying?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I didn't understand your question. I have setup my OpenShift Git repository and have `git push`ed the contents to it from my local repository. I am doing this using the OpenShift console commands (`rhc...`).

Comment: Something is also wrong with your local ssh keys. How did you create them and what did you do to them after creating them?

Comment: The `rhc setup` command automatically created them for me when I ran it at the beginning. Even then I got the `Could not parse PKey: no start line (ArgumentError)` error.